# What's the sql equivalent of a filemaker subsummary?

Tags: mysql, sql, filemaker

I really like the filemaker subsummary reports that can be run, that group items together and give a 'header' of sorts that allows you to count the records, or get info on the current group.  Is their an equivalent in sql that will give me the same result?

For example, if I had a few databases with book titles/authors, and I want to pull a list, and group them by author, with that same header and count for the number of books I have on record that the author wrote:

```
Orson Scott Card (2)
Ender's Game
Ender's Shadow

Frank Herbert (2)
Dune
Dune Messiah

Patrick Rothfus (1)
The Name of the Wind
```

What could I do to get there? I'm mostly interested in if there is a sql solution, not a parsing solution after I get just a list of records.

Comment: [`WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query to get an similar output.

```
SELECT author,count(*) as count,GROUP_CONCAT(title) as titles
  FROM (
    SELECT 'Orson Scott Card' AS author,'Ender\'s Game' as title UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Orson Scott Card','Ender\'s Shadow' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Frank Herbert','Dune' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Frank Herbert','Dune Messiah' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Patrick Rothfus','The Name of the Wind') book
  GROUP BY author;
```

Output:

```
AUTHOR              COUNT       TITLES

Frank Herbert       2           Dune,Dune Messiah
Orson Scott Card    2           Ender's Shadow,Ender's Game
Patrick Rothfus     1           The Name of the Wind
```

But keep in mind that SQL is made to get a table and not a document. This example will probably run into problems if the titles of an authors books become too large.

Comment: Is this useful? I don't see how.

Answer (score 0):

Using some of @oldprogrammer GROUP BY and @marcb WITH ROLLUP was the solution that worked for me, as well as the ORDER BY addition to get it to display the 'subsummary' on top of the authors works.  I use an OFFSET of 1 to omit the first result, which has the total count of returned results.

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
    SELECT author,title, COUNT(title) AS count
    FROM books GROUP BY author,title WITH ROLLUP
    ) t 
ORDER BY author, title
```

Result:

```
Author              Count    Title
Orson Scott Card    2        NULL
Orson Scott Card    1        Ender's Game
Orson Scott Card    1        Ender's Game
Frank Herbert       2        NULL
Frank Herbert       1        Dune
Frank Herbert       1        Dune Messiah
Patrick Rothfuss    1        NULL
Patrick Rothfuss    1        The Name of the Wind
```